# Strong pointer assignment in free_heap

Tags: android, c++, smart-pointers

What's the point of this line:

```
rel = mHeapCache.valueAt(i).heap;
```

In HeapCache::free_heap
[here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/native/libs/binder/IMemory.cpp#445)

I guess it will postpone deallocation of heap till function finish, but why is it done like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it will postpone dealocation of heap till function finish

Exactly. Specifically, it postpones deallocation until after unlocking the mutex, so that it doesn't unnecessarily block access to the cache during that (potentially time-consuming) operation.